# contentful - Retrieving all translations for an entry with the JAVA SDK?

Tags: java, contentful

Today I started to use the Contentful's Content Delivery API with the Java SDK. I'm excited, but I have a problem.

**How can I distribute all of my translations with the Java SDK?**

I found this:

```
curl -X GET "https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/<SPACE_ID>/entries/<ENTRY_ID>?access_token=<CONTENT_DELIVERY_KEY>&locale=*"
```

In the Console it is working perfect, but how can I get all translations with the Java SDK? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
    final CDAArray array = this.contentfulClient
            .fetch(CDAEntry.class)
            .withContentType("message")
            .where("locale", "*")
            .all();
```